# Abrir múltiples ficheros en C

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que abra varios archivos y manipule su contenido. El código funciona para un archivo, pero cuando intento abrir conexión con varios ficheros, aunque se abren ─porque depurando he visto que les asigna un fd a cada uno─, solo modifica el contenido del último fichero pasado.

El código que intenté lo hice con un bucle `for` empezando en 2 porque el 1 es un flag de control que tiene que pasar el usuario para poder usar el programa, por lo que, a partir del argumento 2, se pasan todos los ficheros con los que quiere trabajar.

Código realizado:

```
for(int i=2; i<argc; i++){
    if((fd = open(argv[i], O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        mensaje_error_uso();
        return 1;
    }
    fd=open(argv[i],O_RDWR);
    printf("El fichero %s tiene el fd: %d", argv[i], fd);
}

// llamadas a funciones que manipulan el contenido de los archivos
// ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada variable de tipo `FILE` únicamente puede gestionar un archivo. Si quieres abrir dos archivos a la vez, necestiarás dos variables:

```
FILE* fd1 = open("ruta1", O_RDWR);
FILE* fd2 = open("ruta2", O_RDWR);
```

> ¿Pero y si el número de ficheros que puede pasar el usuario es variable?

Bueno, en ese caso puedes crear un array:

```
int num_ficheros = argc - 2;
FILE** fds = (FILE**)malloc(num_ficheros * sizeof(FILE*));
for( int i=0; i<num_ficheros ; i++)
{
    fds[i] = open(argv[i+2], O_RDWR);
}
```

Comment: Entendido. ¿Pero y si el número de ficheros que puede pasar el usuario es variable? ¿No sería contraproducente por ejemplo, crear tres variables de tipo FILE si luego sólo pasa 2?

Comment: @Oscar he editado la respuesta

Comment: Cierto, con memoria dinámica usando el malloc() se puede. Muchas gracias